How to export large data sets from AWS Aurora Postgres to AWS SQS
We have a massive product table in our AWS Aurora Postgres Cluster. We need to export entries expiring next month (based on the expiry_column) to an AWS SQS queue for processing at the end of the month. The dataset is too large for a single query, so we require a scalable and efficient export method to SQS.
Executing a single large SQL query from the application to export the data is not feasible due to the data volume. Exporting the data in smaller chunks using SQL requires offsets/cursor management for exported entries in a distributed environment, which significantly increases the complexity of our setup.
The plan is to deploy a cluster of Spring Batch applications that will handle the AWS SQS in a distributed manner starting from specific date, to send notifications and perform business logic on the queue entries.
Any guidance or suggestions on the best approach to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

I would recommend separating the process into two steps: First, export the data to a file using query_export_to_s3(). Then, use that data to (somehow) publish the SQS messages. See: Exporting data from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster to Amazon S3 - Amazon Aurora

What type of compute are you planning to use to run the Spring batch? Would you implement a cluster with Docker images managed with EKS?
I believe you can implement a custom partitioning strategy by using SELECT *,        NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS part FROM your_table WHERE expiry_column = 'date' ;
Configure your Spring Batch applications to use the custom partitioning strategy for reading data from the Aurora database and writing records to the SQS queue.
